# Why is my $node always null in my custom block (using plugin contexts)?

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I am trying to make a block that gets the current node via Plugin Contexts.

But my `$node` is always null. Can anyone tell me why?

I am placing the block with the context module if that makes a difference?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Header' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "header",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Header"),
 *   context = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", required = FALSE)
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ProductStickyHeader extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $node = $this->getContextValue('node');
    // $node is always null!

    return $build;
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: "I am placing the block with the context module if that makes a difference?" Yes that possibly makes all the difference, quite possible that the context module doesn't support that. Try using the default block UI to confirm that

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone - turns out the answer was deceptively simple - I had to remove the block using context & then re-add it. When I re-added it there was an extra option in context to use the current node. Then the context plugin worked!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to get the current node in a block is to use the route parameters.  E.g.:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ( $node == NULL || $node->getType() != 'blog_post') {
  return;
}
```

Comment: The recommended way is definitely to use block contexts not this, because that will for example take care of cache contexts, which this does not and you need to make sure your block is properly cached yourself. But if the module instantiating the block plugins doesn't support that, then you need to fall back to this, yes